# Lock screen orientation to portrait when scanning with Zxing library, Xamarin.android app.

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, zxing

I've seen it can be done in camera configuration manager but not sure where to find that file???

I've added:

```
          <activity android:name="MainActivity"

          android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" 

          android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
```

And now the mainactivity is locked on portrait, but when running zxing scanner from inside activity the screen rotates during scan??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solved the issue, very simple in the end. I'm using Zxing.net.mobile, not          zxing.net which is slightly different...

```
            var scanner = new MobileBarcodeScanner();
            scanner.TopText = "Scanning for Barcode...";
            var result = await scanner.Scan(new MobileBarcodeScanningOptions
            {
                AutoRotate = false
            });
            if (result != null)
            {
                _scan.ScanValue = result.ToString();
                _scan.Action = "Scan";
                await CallService();
            }
            else
            {
                scanner.Cancel();
                Recreate();
            }
        };
```

This works well.

Comment: Now I want an option to scan in landscape! but locked on landscape. When using autorotate=false, it starts in portrait and is locked. I'm hoping there's a way to start in landscape and lock on landscape, when required.

Comment: if ou first do RequestedOrientation = Android.Content.PM.ScreenOrientation.Landscape; and then set autorotate to false?

Comment: Na that dosent seem to do it, i tried this before calling scanner.scan...
if(scanner.Scan().Status == TaskStatus.Running)
                {
                    RequestedOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Landscape;
                }

Answer (score 5):

Add this to your Main activity to lock orientation

```
[Activity (Label = "YourLabel", MainLauncher = true, ScreenOrientation = Android.Content.PM.ScreenOrientation.Landscape)]
```

To change the orientation with code use this:

```
if (scanning)
    RequestedOrientation = Android.Content.PM.ScreenOrientation.Portrait;
```

Comment: I found similar code to do this with iOS but I could never figure out how to reset it back to changing orientation when the user rotates their device. How would you do it on Android?

Comment: my example is for android, every time you want to change the orientation use this code: RequestedOrientation = Android.Content.PM.ScreenOrientation.Portrait; // or .Landscape; 

if you need a more specific example please show me your code, when and how the scanning start and when it ends

Comment: maybe its just a dll file, the code ScreenOrientation = Android.Content.PM.ScreenOrientation.Landscape) is able to lock the orientation or the scan can bypass even this line that is defined on the Activity?

Comment: still having no luck with the rotation it seems like whatever i try gets ignored once scanner screen starts.